# Unable to load ad using adMob in android

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I tried using the testing Id, it displays the ad. Later on I put my own ID but it didn't display any ads.

Code:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(TestAd.this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adunitid));
        AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
       ad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(TestAd.this, "Ad Not Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                        super.onAdClosed();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Java file for initialising:

```
public class Admob extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
    }}
```

Android Manifest :

```
android:name="com.test.Admob"
```

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/appid"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You cannot show the live ads on debug mode,
If it is working with the test ids it should be cool with real ids when you release the app, as well.

But there is one more thing that you can use, I mean to be sure everything is working.

First of all, make every ids real contains the id at the manifest file.

After running your app, open your Logcat and simply write

> test

like this,

[image]

get that id and update your `AdRequest` like this

```
AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("id_here").build();
```

and re-run your app.

Congrats, you can see your ads with your real ids now! hope it helps!

**UPDATE:**

Old usage looks deprecated thanks @heisenberg3008

as the google suggests [current usage](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) should be like this

```
List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("id_here");
RequestConfiguration configuration =
    new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

it is a one-time thing. So, no need to do that for every ad item, like before

Comment: addTestDevice is deprecated now.

Comment: List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231");
RequestConfiguration configuration =
    new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration); 
This is what is recommended on Google's test ads page. But I dont know where do I paste this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads @haliltprkk

Comment: yes it looks deprecated, the new version has better usage

Comment: I have pasted the code above. Do you know where are we supposed to put it? @haliltprkk

Comment: Yes actually, You need to do this at where you initialize your MobileAds, I am talking about this code MobileAds.initialize(this);

Comment: Generally, it should be made at the top level application, do you have a class that top of everything and extends Application class ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212353/discussion-between-haliltprkk-and-heisenberg3008).